# Find location of a text in image

Tags: c#

In my application I am checking various websites and making sure that the websites are up and send email notifications if they are down.

When they get down, my program takes snap of the the browser and send it to support.

The problem is that the images that I send have CardNumber(like username) visible in it.  I have found a way to remove rectangular portion from any image at fixed coordinates. But the problem is that for the various websites the CardNumber appear at different places.

Is there any DLL available that can let me know where the string CardNumber appear in the image and give me its X,Y coordinates.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear how this text appears on your image if the site is down? I think we could think of easier solution if you clarify that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-sharp-ocr-library

Comment: @DavidGoshadze If the website is down, the pic woud be blank. If the website is down due to some known message like "password is wrong" etc, the cardnumber would be there.

Comment: Does it rendered in html as picture or as text? I mean probably it would be much easier to parse html, remove that block, then render it on screen and take screenshot